# Passing dependency parameters to App::make() or App::makeWith() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container

I have a class that uses a dependency. I need to be able to dynamically set parameters on the dependency from the controller:

```
$objDependency = new MyDependency();
$objDependency->setSomething($something);
$objDependency->setSomethingElse($somethingElse);

$objMyClass = new MyClass($objDependency);
```

How do I achieve this through the Service Container in Laravel? This is what I've tried but this seems wrong to me. In my AppServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->bind('MyClass', function($app,$parameters){

    $objDependency = new MyDependency();
    $objDependency->setSomething($parameters['something']);
    $objDependency->setSomethingElse($parameters['somethingElse']);

    return new MyClass($objDependency);
}
```

And then in the controller i'd use this like:

```
$objMyClass = App:make('MyClass', [
    'something'     => $something, 
    'somethingElse' => $somethingElse
]);
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way and this is kind of a factory design pattern implementation of Laravel. What bothers you with this code?

Comment: Thank you - I'm not sure, I'm still getting to know Laravel and I just wasn't sure if it was correct to set the dependency's parameters. Thanks again

Comment: You could inject your dependencies directly in the constructor though.

Answer (score 37):

You can see detailed documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#the-make-method

It's done like this:

```
$api = $this->app->makeWith('HelpSpot\API', ['id' => 1]);
```

Or use the app() helper

```
$api = app()->makeWith(HelpSpot\API::class, ['id' => 1]);
```

It is **essential** to set the array key as the argument variable name, otherwise it will be ignored. So if your code is expecting a variable called $modelData, the array key needs to be 'modelData'.

```
$api = app()->makeWith(HelpSpot\API::class, ['modelData' => $modelData]);
```

Note: if you're using it for mocking, makeWith does not return Mockery instance.

Comment: One thing to make sure you do is to pass the parameter name as the array key. I didn't' do this and it silently fails, which isn't fun to debug!

Comment: @MatthewInamdar Wow I wish I saw your comment sooner! This was driving me nuts!

Comment: Also supported: `app(HelpSpot\API::class, ['modelData' => $modelData])`

Answer (score 9):

You can also do it this way:

```
$this->app->make(SomeClass::class, ["foo" => 'bar']);
```